# jQuery bxSlider Plugin not working in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am a beginner in Angular 5 Framework. I have create a project and working on it but I am facing a problem with bxSlider. I have added a bxSlider plugin in myangular project. It seems ok when it load first. But when I click On other page link and get back to my index page the bxSlider plugin doesn't work.

**1) Here is cutsom.js file.**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

$('.homeSlider').bxSlider({
    speed: 1500,
    pause: 5000,
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    auto: false,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    stopAuto: false,
    pager: false,
    nextSelector: '#slider-next',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
});
```

});

**2) app.component.ts file**

```
declare var jquer:any;
declare var $:any;
```

I have declare both jquery and $ object in my component file.

When the site load it looks like this.
[image]

After I change the page and get back to my index page the whole slider breakdown.

[image]

Comment: Should this be `declare var jquery:any;`? have you added type defiition reference in your app.component for jquery?

Comment: Here is my app.component.ts file code http://prntscr.com/hf0ky6. I have replace the "let" with "var". But still it's not working. Slider fully works at first but it doesn't work after i change the link and get back to index page.

Comment: Can you post the code rather than in external sites

Comment: ok. Here is my app.component.ts file code. import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App Wroks!';

}

Answer (score 2):

move the code from custom.js to `ngOnInit() {}` life cycle method inside your component file. whenever the component is loaded it will initialize the slider. No need of writing document ready function.

Comment: import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    $('.homeSlider').bxSlider({
    speed: 1500,
    pause: 5000,
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    auto: false,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    stopAuto: false,
    pager: false,
    nextSelector: '#slider-next',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
});
  }

Comment: Thanks a lot now it's working. Really appreciate it.

Comment: *ngFor is a directive, not a lifecycle hookup. what is your exact requirement

Comment: I meant to say will it work with dynamic imageurl inside ngfor attribute ?

Comment: @sarojsharma Have you include jquery & bxslider JS in anguar.json file?